# PHP PDO UPDATE not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've building a web application and am having difficulties getting my UPDATE query to actually update the data in the database.

This is my code:

```
function changeTeam($id, $newteam){
  $dbID = getTeamId($newteam);
  $conn = connectdb();
  $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE users SET team_id = :team WHERE _id = :id');
  $stmt->execute(array('team' => $dbID, 'id' => $id));
}
```

I've verified that the correct variables are being passed into the function, and that the `getTeamId()` function works correctly.  I've also taken the statement and run it with phpMyAdmin using the same values that are being passed into the function.  This also worked fine.

I have enabled pdo error reporting using `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`, and no errors are being reported.

Is there something that I am obviously missing?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try, `$stmt->execute(array('team' => $dbID, 'id' => $id)) or die(print_r($stmt->errorInfo()));`

Comment: is your column definitely called _id?

Comment: I just tried that.  It didn't cause the function to die.  To double check, I put a return statement below that and it reached that statement fine.

Comment: And yes, the column is called "_id" for sure.

Comment: oooh, could be the autocommit, check it.

Comment: how are you using the function; could be a variable scope issue.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I tried adding that line to the top of my files, and no errors were returned.

Here is the file that the function is being called from: http://pastebin.com/xauwud7i

Comment: Are you sure PDO is installed on your server? I had an issue where PDO was not working because it was not installed on a vps.

Comment: Yes, PDO is installed because other SELECT and INSERT commands are working.

Comment: Both variables are populated in the function correctly? `print_r(array('team' => $dbID, 'id' => $id));` in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Look, there is no magic. Really. Nothing mysterious in programming. To make an update work, you have to provide your query with proper values and see that it threw no errors. That's all. Nothing extraordinary is required. Just the proper syntax, the proper data in the database and no errors during update. That's all.

You may say a thousand times that you have all your variables correctly set, but until you **make them so**, and **verify that are so,**  all your updates will fail.

Answer (score -1):

you need to change this `$stmt->execute(array('team' => $dbID, 'id' => $id));` to `$stmt->execute(array(':team' => $dbID, ':id' => $id));` I think you are missing the colon for the parameters.

Comment: [PHP PDO Statement Execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) look at example 2 the parameters have the colon. I still think that will solve the issue when he puts the colons in.

Comment: have you tried `echo $id` and `echo $dbid` to make sure that the variables are being filled correctly? Also, maybe a semi-colon at the end of the SQL statement.

Comment: why do people contradict me.

Comment: I was merely pointing out that the documentation was different than the supplied code and from what I am used to seeing. It may work both ways but I prefer to follow the documentation's way of doing things.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `team_id`=? WHERE _id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($dbID, $id));
```

Comment: Try this $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `team_id`=? WHERE _id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($dbID, $id));

Comment: Sorry I had the first question mark in square brackets